# How do you solve the circular table problem?

Tags: mathematics, josephus-problem

One classic puzzle has many different forms, but the basic strategy is the same.

> Once upon a time there was a crazy king who had a very wise minister
> with him. The king had a habit of playing a strange game on a circular table.
>
> The game was played as follows: The king told his minister a different number everyday -
> let's say he says 5. Then minister would then arrange five people and ask
> them to sit in a circular table with five chairs. Starting from a specific person, the king would then kill every
> second person on the table, until only one remained at the end, to which he would give 1,000 gold coins.
>
> For example, if there were five people on the table, starting from
> person 1, he would kill person 2, person 4, person 1, and person 5 (skipping over persons 2 and 4 since they are already dead),
> leaving person 3 as the survivor and winner.
>
> Now the wise minister was so clever as to calculate the winner
> beforehand as soon as king said the number, and asked his man to sit
> at particular seat so as to not be killed and also win some gold.
>
> How did the minister decide the winner?

Comment: How does the king decide where to start killing?

Comment: Let's say chair very next to his place to sit is considered as first chair daily. But its the same everyday.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is known as the [Josephus problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem).  If the number of people $n$ is expressed as $n=2^m+p$, with $m$ as large as possible, the survivor is in seat $2p+1$  Another way to express it is to write $n$ in binary and rotate left one position.  For example, let there be $19$ people at the table, so we write $19=2^4+3$ and the winner is $2\cdot 3+1=7$, or  $19_{10}=10011_2$  Left rotating one space gives $00111_2=7_{10}$

Comment: See also [A006257](https://oeis.org/A006257).

Comment: Sorry for dumb question but I did not get the definition of m, n and p. Can you please explain what are the values of m,n and p in the example I explained in question?

Comment: In your example, $n=5, m=2, p=1$, because there are $5=2^2+1$ people at the table and the winner is in seat $2 \cdot 1+1=3$.  For another example (because with small numbers it can be confusing what comes from where), if there were $19$ people at the table, we would write $19=2^4+3$ and the winner would be in seat $2 \cdot 3+1=7$