# What is the solution to the generic round table problem?

Tags: calculation-puzzle, josephus-problem

[This question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/371/how-do-you-solve-the-circular-table-problem) was asked about a group of people whom a king wishes to play a cruel game with. Going around in a circle, the king kills every other person.

The question concerned how one could compute the answer without executing the sequence, and this answer comes out to $n=2^m+p$, where $n$ is the number of people, $2^m$ is the highest value less than $n$, and $p$ is the seat number of the person who lives.

What happens if the king kills every third person? Fourth person? For convenience, let $s$ be the number of seats skipped.

I've worked out the first few digits in the sequence where $s=3$, as $1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 4, 7$, but I don't see a pattern here. I imagine I'd have to generate quite a number of these to see the pattern. The first few digits where $s=4$ are $1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 5, 2, 6, 1$.

How does one generate this sequence in a generic way for any $s$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the previous thread, this is the (generalized) [Josephus problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem), known as such because the oldest known reference (at least in Western history) is by the historian [Flavius Josephus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavius_Josephus).

There is no known general closed form. You can compute the position of the survivor by recurrence:
$$p_s^n = \begin{cases}
  1 + (p^{n-1}_s - 1 + s) \bmod n & \text{if \(n \gt 1\)} \\
  1 & \text{if \(n = 1\)} \\
\end{cases}$$
where $p_s^n$ is position of the survivor for the $s$-step Josephus problem with $n$ people.

The [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/) should always be your first hit when you have a sequence of integers. It has a [bunch of entries tagged “Josephus”](https://oeis.org/wiki/Index_to_OEIS%3a_Section_J), including

- [A006257](https://oeis.org/A006257): survivor for $s=2$
- [A054995](https://oeis.org/A054995): survivor for $s=3$
- [A088333](https://oeis.org/A088333): survivor for $s=4$
- [A181281](https://oeis.org/A181281): survivor for $s=5$
- [A032434](https://oeis.org/A032434): $p_s^n+1$ for $s \le n$, in lexicographic order of $(s,n)$

The reference for A054995 gives a formula for $s=3$:
$$p^3_n = 3n+1 - \lfloor K(3) \cdot (3/2)^{\lceil L(3) \rceil} \rfloor$$
where $ L(3) = \dfrac{\log((2n+1)/K(3))}{\log(3/2)} $
and $K(3) \approx 1.62227050288476731595695$ as seen in [A083286](https://oeis.org/A083286). See [“Functional iteration and the Josephus problem”](ftp://ftp.cis.upenn.edu/pub/wilf/josephus.ps) by A. M. Odlyzko and H. S. Wilf for a proof and generalization. There is also a proof with didactic commentary in *Concrete Mathematics* (Graham, Knuth and Patashnik, 1994 (2nd ed.)) §3.3. Note that this doesn't really help to compute the values, because computing a precise enough value of $K(3)$ is as hard as computing $p^3_n$.